# How to find f(x+a)?

Tags: integration

Let f be a function defined by $$f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt,x>0$$

Then we have to find the value of $$\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t+a}dt$$

**Here's what I did:**

$$f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\int_1^x\frac{e^{t+a}}{t+a}d(t+a)=$$

$$\implies\ \int_1^x\frac{e^t}{t+a}dt=e^{-a}f(x)$$

However, these are the options given:

a)$e^a[f(x+a)-f(1+a)]$

b)$e^{-a}[f(x+a)-f(1+a)]$

c)$e^a[f(x)-f(1+a)]$

d)$e^{-a}[f(x+a)-f(a)]$

(The square brackets are just for enhancing readability, not the floor function)

How do I proceed?

Comment: Don't forget to change the limits of integration when you make the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a substitution in
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{1}^x \frac{e^t}{t}\; dt = \int_{1 + a}^{x+a}\frac{e^{t+a}}{t+a}\; dt \\
&= -\int_{1}^{1+a} \frac{e^{t+a}}{x+a}\; dt + \int_1^{x+a} \frac{e^{t+a}}{t+a}\; dt. \\
&= -e^a\int_{1}^{1+a} \frac{e^{t}}{t+a}\; dt + e^a\int_1^{x+a} \frac{e^{t}}{t+a}\; dt. \\
\end{align}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Looks like I missed something very basic, changing the limits! Yes, thanks, it is quite clear now.

Comment: @Shubham: Indeed

Comment: @Shubham You can check this answer off as the correct answer by hitting the check mark.  This will also help you get more replies to your questions if people realize you accept their answers as the correct one.  Thanks.  +1

Comment: @Integrals, Yes, I was about to check it! It required 4 minutes!